# Explosions not rendering but showing up in viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

I am trying to create an explosion in Blender. However, when I try to render the explosion, nothing happens, but I can see the explosion in the viewport. Am I doing something wrong, or did I forget to do something?

> <strike>Note: I have two domains because apparently the smoke will flicker if I only use one.</strike>
>
> EDIT: They've fixed this bug.

[image: This is what it looks like in the viewport]
[image: This is what it looks like when I'm rendering it.]

The Blend File:
[Download the file](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Me4jwUDSXPQzdISHR0Y1Vhbnc)

(apparently I can't post 2 links)

Comment: Did you create an appropriate material for the smoke domain?

Comment: I used the material generated using the Quick Smoke, "Smoke Domain Material"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid everything in Cycles, and everything seems to be working fine. It seems that I may have had a problem with lighting the the original render.

[image: Explosion]